# No sound from headphone Dell XPS 13 ubuntu studio 18.04

Tags: sound, dell, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm a Linux noob and I bought this fresh Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 18.04 natively installed. Then I installed Ubuntu studio (I work with audio). Everything audio-related looks fine. But:

I have no sound from headphone jack. I checked everything AFAIK on askubuntu on related threads. Sound level for headphone shows up correctly in pavucontrol and alsamixer says nothing is muted. I also removed some config files as suggested bvy another answer. I also modified the BIOS and rebooted.
This is my alsa diagnose file:

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=493c1ce3f01136cd76d40456e5e66e183c127c99

Frankly I have no idea where the issue is.
Thanks
-a-

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work by adding the following line to the bottom of `/etc/pulse/system.pa`

You need sudo rights to access this file.  i.e

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/system.pa
```

Add this at the bottom of the file:

```
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

```
Yes
enter
```

Reboot to restart `pulseaudio` and you will find the headphones now work as required.

There's probably a nicer/easier way to append this line to the file but the above worked for me!

Comment: Thanks, I solved by re-installing ubuntu, much better than ubuntu-studio, the latter has a lot of issues, it really does not work properly